# How can I create records in database when application boot or restarted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, boot, records

In my application I have a sing_up_page which has a sing_up_form which has a drop_down_list Which shows the role_type.

RoleType is the class in application in which I have stored records

```
insert into role_type (id,name) values (1,'user');
insert into role_type (id,name) values (1,'admin');
insert into role_type (id,name) values (1,'vender');
```

manually in database before starting the application. Before moving to the sing_up_page I do

`@role_type=RoleType.all`

so that drop down can use it to display role_types but I want If their is a procedure to produce these records at the boot time of the application without manually creating records in database as in Groovy on Grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a `.rb` file in `app/config/initializers/`, it will be executed when the server loads.

Example:

`app/config/initializers/seed.rb`

```
%w{user admin vendor}.each do |role|
  RoleType.create(:name => role)
end
```

Every time the server loads, these records will be created.

**Question:** why are these records not retained in your database? Are you or someone else deleting them?

Comment: I want these records to be created only once when the application is first time run on another machine/server. After then they will be made comment.

Comment: You can check if `RoleType`'s exist or use the built in `rake db:seed` command that runs a seeds file in `db/seed.rb` but that command has to be run manually.